# UWP Google Analytics full integration Tutorial needed

Tags: google-analytics, uwp

I have created a UWP app and integrated google analytics SDK in it from the following link https://github.com/dotnet/windows-sdk-for-google-analytics. Since the help of this library does not portray a complete work flow I need a working example to set things up with analytics. I want to track product additions and checkouts. I am able to send page views and clicks to analytics as well as bundle up product details with hit requests.

Please help me to understand how to see the sent products in Google Analytics dashboard and reports.

Comment: It has documentation on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/windows-sdk-for-google-analytics/wiki/Documentation  Have you check the [Getting Started to use Google Analytics](https://github.com/dotnet/windows-sdk-for-google-analytics/wiki/Getting-Started)?

Comment: Okay, it helped. Thanks... I figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get Google Analytics working with UWP. I wrapped up my data with events and prepared custom reports in Analytics dashboard on the basis of wrapped data.